# Is the average associator over a finite subloop of octonions necessarily zero?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, octonions, non-associative-algebras

For any three octonions $a,b,c$, their associator is defined as \begin{equation*} [a,b,c]=a(bc)-(ab)c \end{equation*} and measures their non-associativity so to speak.

Now suppose that $L$ is a finite non-associative subloop of $\mathbb{O}$ and that $\{x_\ell\}_{\ell\in L}$ is a collection of arbitrary (distinct) octonions, indexed by $L$. If $h$ is any element of $L$, is the "average associator"
\begin{equation} \frac{1}{|L|}\sum_{\ell\in L} [h,\ell^{-1},x_\ell]\end{equation}
necessarily zero?

Some motivation for the question: the sum $\frac{1}{|L|}\sum_{\ell\in L} \ell^{-1} x_\ell$ is something like a Fourier transform for a an injection $f\colon L\to \mathbb{O}$. A zero average associator would mean that $\sum_\ell \ell^{-1}f(\ell h)=h\sum_\ell \ell^{-1}f(\ell)$, so that the transform is equivariant with respect to $L$.

Comment: This is a neat question!  By the way, TeX-style quotes don't work here; you can use dumb quotes "" or Unicode quotes “”, but ``'' doesn't get fixed up and so looks strange.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but the $x_l$ all look independent from each other, so what prohibits you to take all of them 0 except for one of them, and choose the remaining one so that the corresponding associator is nonzero?

Comment: This is a good point. I guess I should give some sort of generiticity condition on the $x_\ell$. Still, your observation leads me to think the average needn't be zero even generically

Comment: I edited so that the $x_\ell$ are all distinct

Comment: Since the expression is linear in the vector formed by the $x_l$, and the collection of such vectors with distinct entries spans the space of all such vectors ($\mathbb{O}^L$), the distinctness assumption doesn't change anything.